# how to center tiles horizontally in Bulma?

Tags: html, css, centering, bulma

I am using Bulma for my portfolio website. In the ["how to reach me"](https://photeus.info/howtoreachme) section, I'd like to put my personal profiles on social networks for information. In the best, the tiles with my profiles would be centered horizontally. But I don't know how to achieve it with Bulma.

Here is the code of the tiles :

```css
.tile {
  text-align: center;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div className="container">
    <div className="tile is-ancestor">
        <div className="tile is-parent is-vertical"  >
          <div className="tile is-child is-4 box">
            <p className="title">Linkedin</p>
            <a href="linkedin.com/in/frederic--lang" >Frédéric Lang</a>
          </div>
          <div className="tile is-child is-4 box">
            <p className="title">Twitter</p>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/Fredestrik?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @Fredestrik</a><script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
          </div>
          <div className="tile is-child is-4 box">
            <p className="title">Github</p>
            <a href="https://github.com/Fredestrik">Frédéric Lang</a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would appreciate any help about how to center these tiles. I tried some tricks like CSS {text-align: center} or {margin: auto} but it does not seem to work. Maybe it is a bulma preset that does not allow it.
Best regards,
Frédéric

Comment: do you want to build blocks horizontally?

Comment: do you want it like that? - https://i.postimg.cc/RZ6sM5VK/image.png

Comment: no, I would like to have my blocks stack vertically, but a the center of my page ;-)

Comment: ok, I'll do it now.

Comment: https://ibb.co/ThkdFX8 - like this?

Comment: yes exactly ! how did you make it ?

Comment: now I will send you a solution and an explanation :)

Comment: do you have access to the `.tile` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.tile` already has `flex` display, and `.tile.is-vertical` has `flex-direction: column`. To center social media blocks, you just need to add the `align-items: center` rule. Like this:

```
.tile {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

If this rule overrides another rule (`align-items: stretch`), then do it like this:

```
.tile {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center!important;
}
```

Comment: thanks! it works!
In order to not impact the alignment of text inside tiles, I just make these rule on the is-parent bulma class. After this, the result is as expected

Comment: Ok well. Happy to help